# Django - No Reverse Match at /

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the absolute url for particular items in my model.

models.py

```
class BannerAds(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('index', args=[str(self.name)])
```

views.py

```
def banners(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    all_banners = BannerAds.objects.all()
    content_dict = {'banners': all_banners,}
    return render_to_response('templates/banner.html', content_dict, context)


def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    banner_list = BannerAds.objects.all()
    city_list = Cities.objects.order_by('name')
    offer_list = NewOffers.objects.order_by('offer_add_date')[:5]
    context_dic = {'banner_list': banner_list,
                   'cities': city_list,
                   'offers': offer_list,
                   }
    return render_to_response('templates/index.html', context_dic, context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^advertise/', views.advertise, name='advertise'),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^listing/', views.listing, name='listing'),
    url(r'^search/', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^add/', views.add_listing, name='add'),
    url(r'^offers/', views.offers, name='offer'),
    url(r'^add_listing/$', views.add_listing, name='add_listing'),
    url(r'^listing/(?P<listing_url>\w+)/$', views.listing, name='category'),
    url(r'^testimonial/', views.testimonials, name='testimonial'),
    url(r'^add_testimonial', views.add_testimonial, name='add_testimonial'),
    url(r'^banner', views.banners, name='banners'),
)
```

I've entered test data as name=test, phone = testing.

When I try to open the page, it gives me a `No Reverse Match at /` error along with a 
`Reverse for '' with arguments '('Testing',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Any idea what I'm missing? I'm pretty new to Django development so solutions with code examples would help me a lot.

Comment: show the `urls.py` file which contains url for view

Comment: @AamirAdnan, added urls.py

Answer (score 0):

Change the view `banners` to as you are passing args.

```
def banners(request, name):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    all_banners = BannerAds.objects.all()
    content_dict = {'banners': all_banners,}
    return render_to_response('templates/banner.html', content_dict, context)
```

Also, make sure you have made an entry in urls.py with `name="banners"`

Comment: Sayan, I realised that I wanted to pass the url to the index view. So I've added the `index` view to `views.py` in the above edit. Please have a look and let me know what the solution is.

Comment: Did you add the `name` as an argument in the view?

Comment: I should be adding it to `def index(request, name):` right? I added it, but it gives me the error of index requires 2 parameters but is getting only 1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use both `@permalink` and `reverse()`. They do the same thing. Either drop the decorator, or just return the tuple of (view_name, args).

In fact, the documentation says that permalink is deprecated, so the best thing is just to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The url `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')` does not accept any parameter so why are you passing args here `reverse('index', args=[str(self.name)])`?

If you want a detail view and wants the `name` to be optional parameter for `index` then you can do:

```
url(r'^(?:(?P<name>.+?)/)?$', views.index, name='index')
```

Also change the `index` view to this:

```
def index(request, name=None):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    banner_list = BannerAds.objects.all()

    # now if name parameter is not None you may want to just pick single object
    banner_obj = None
    if name:
        banner_obj = BannerAds.objects.get(name__exact=name)

    city_list = Cities.objects.order_by('name')
    offer_list = NewOffers.objects.order_by('offer_add_date')[:5]
    context_dic = {'banner_list': banner_list,
                   'cities': city_list,
                   'offers': offer_list,
                   'banner_obj': banner_obj,
                   }
    return render_to_response('templates/index.html', context_dic, context)
```

Or have a separate view which will serve for the detail of `BannerAds`.